# Where to download .osm files and how to convert it to .xml?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osmosis

I am new to deal with OSM data, and I want to download only .osm files not .pbf. I tried geofabrik.com but it provides .osm.pbf file format

1. where can I download .osm files?
2. is there any recommended way to convert .osm files to .xml?

Comment: As per the [Tour] please ask only one question per question.  Also, this seems to be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/172177/115.

Comment: It is not duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172177/osm-filter-and-converter-is-not-working in any way shape or form. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172177/osm-filter-and-converter-is-not-working is about problem with osmfilter setup.

Answer (score 4):

1. where can I download .osm files

Just go again to Geofabrik to get files with extension `.osm.bz2`: it's `.osm` files compressed using `.bz2` (it's like `.zip` but with an alternate compression).

After getting `.osm.bz2`, uncompress them. You will get the `.osm` files.

2. is there any recommended way to convert `.osm` files to `.xml`?

There are no conversion step to xml: an `.osm` file is an xml file (open it with a text editor and look the first line). You misunderstand relationship between extensions and serialisation (XML).